# Date is being inserted at 44625 instead of correct format

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list box that if I double click a list item it insets that data back into the corresponding textbox's, when the date is transferred over instead of being 4/12/2022 it 44625.

Comment: you need to format the value to the output you want.  How is the data being transferred to the textbox?

Comment: By double clicking an item in the list box.

Comment: okay then probably have some code somewhere that transfers the data to the textbox.  In that code you need to use `Format` to set the format of the string.

Comment: Ok, sorry pretty new to this whole thing but I think this is the code I have tranfering the date, how would I put it in there?                                                    Me.Date_Item_Found_Textbox.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)

Comment: `Me.Date_Item_Found_Textbox.Value = Format(Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1),"mm/dd/yyyy")`  Change the `mm/dd/yyyy` to what ever format you want to see in the output.

Comment: Awesome works perfect thank you